# Pass array variable from Vue to scss

Tags: vue.js, variables, sass, vuejs3, sass-loader

I have a project with Vujs3, and use sass. I got list of images names through API in my Vue component and I want to pass it to scss to write stiles with background-image;

```js
export default {
  name: 'TestComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      skills: ['test1', 'test2'], //here I will got my array through API
    }
  }
}
<style lang="scss">
$skills: v-bind(skills); // it doesn't correct I just wanted that it worked somehow like that

@each $skill in $skills {
  .skills__cell-inner_#{$skill} {
    background-image: url("@/assets/images/skills-icons/#{$skill}.svg");
  }
}
</style>
```

I know that sass is compiled before the app launches, but I just curious how this task could be perform.

I am expecting that after I got array with images names, I could write css styles in scss using those names and set background-images

Comment: This is a tricky one. You could use css custom properties or generate your own style tag. You could use the  `useStyleTag` composable provided by https://vueuse.org/core/useStyleTag/#usestyletag

Comment: Another option would be to create a skill component that you iterate in vue (not in SCSS) where you pass the current skill as property and inside the Skill component you bind the skill value to a css value. This would be the best approach i would say. If you find yourself doing some wired stuff that seems not to work, often the way how you do it is the problem ;)

Comment: @LeifMarcus thank you for answering :-) I’m also inclined to think that creating a component with iteration would be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, use inline style in template scope.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).